# Is there any kind of package that includes a function to smooth out, or even out distribution in array by deleting samples?

Tags: python, data-science

I have an array of values that range from 0 to 1 that relates to the output truth values for a neural network I'm building. However the distribution is very wide and uneven, so I was curious if there was a package for Python that could remove samples so that the distribution is more even across the array.

Here's the distribution plot from seaborn's `seaborn.distplot()`.

[image]

What I'd like to do is essentially specify a value of how many 'sections' to break the array into, and to remove values from the largest sections so that the distribution is more even.

The plot from the output of this function would probably look something like this:

[image]

Does there exist any kind of built-in package for numpy, or scipy to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this can help anyone in the future, here's what I came up with:

```
def reject_outliers(x_t, y_t, m):
    mean = np.mean(y_t)
    std = np.std(y_t)
    x_t, y_t = zip(*[[x, y] for x, y in zip(x_t, y_t) if abs(y - mean) < (m * std)])
    return list(x_t), np.array(y_t)


def even_out_distribution(x_t, y_t, n_sections, reduction=0.5, reduce_min=.5, m=2):
    x_t, y_t = reject_outliers(x_t, y_t, m)
    linspace = np.linspace(np.min(y_t), np.max(y_t), n_sections + 1)
    sections = [[] for i in range(n_sections)]
    for x, y in zip(x_t, y_t):
        where = max(np.searchsorted(linspace, y) - 1, 0)
        sections[where].append([x, y])
    sections = [sec for sec in sections if sec != []]

    min_section = min([len(i) for i in sections])  # np.mean([len(i) for i in sections]) * reduce_min  # todo: in replace of min([len(i) for i in sections])
    print([len(i) for i in sections])
    new_sections = []
    for section in sections:
        this_section = list(section)
        if len(section) > min_section:
            to_remove = (len(section) - min_section) * reduction
            for i in range(int(to_remove)):
                this_section.pop(random.randrange(len(this_section)))

        new_sections.append(this_section)
    print([len(i) for i in new_sections])
    output = [inner for outer in new_sections for inner in outer]
    x_t, y_t = zip(*output)

    return list(x_t), np.array(y_t)
```

I made it so that if it deletes a sample from `y_train`, it deletes it from your input list, or `x_train`.

Usage: `x, y = even_out_distribution(x_train, y_train, n_sections=10, m=2, reduction=.8)`
and now my distribution plot looks a lot nicer now!

[image]